# Inline edit html table with ajax php checkbox & select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Final Edit:** I abandoned trying to get checkboxes to work with this method. Instead, I'm just using a combo box with a 'Yes' and 'No'. Combos are working perfectly, thanks to some fantastic help from SE users :) It actually turns out to be better, IMO. Checkboxes with inline editing, the way I've implemented it could lead to accidentally checked or unchecked boxes. A combo is an extra 2 clicks but it's worth it to eliminate accidents. It also looks great because I'm just swapping a little red 'x' or green 'check' to indicate on and off. It looks really nice. Thanks again to everyone for your help!

I'm using the method from [9lessons.info](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html) to create a table with inline-editable rows. So far, it's working but not very well when it comes to selects and checkboxes. With selects, it does update the value, but when it hides the input (when clicking outside the tr) the value of the select shows (the fk id field), rather than the text in between opening and closing of the selected option tag (the name field). I can see in the jQuery where it shows the value, but how do I tell it to use the text from the option instead of the value?

the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit_tr").click(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        // hide
        $("#name_"+ID).hide();
        $("#position_"+ID).hide();
        $("#parent_nav_"+ID).hide();
        $("#is_disp_"+ID).hide();
        // show
        $("#name_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#position_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#parent_nav_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#is_disp_input_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function(){
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var name=$("#name_input_"+ID).val();
        var position=$("#position_input_"+ID).val();
        var parent_nav = $("#parent_nav_input_"+ID).val();
        var is_disp = $("#is_disp_"+ID).prop("checked") ? 1 : 0;
        // data string
        var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&name='+name+'&position='+position+'&parent_nav='+parent_nav+'&is_disp='+is_disp;

        if(name.length > 0 && position.length > 0 && parent_nav.length > 0) {
            var parent_nav_txt = $("#parent_nav_input_"+ID+" option:selected").text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "admin_nav_edit.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#name_"+ID).html(name);
                    $("#position_"+ID).html(position);
                    $("#parent_nav_"+ID).html(parent_nav_txt);
                    $("#is_disp_"+ID).html(is_disp);
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Enter something.');
        }
    });
    //edit input box click action
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
        return false
    });
    //outsire click action
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(".editbox").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });
});
```

I know the 'is_disp' variables in script are not retrieving the right thing, but everything else works so I don't think I need to post the rest of my code, but I will if necessary.

So, what should I put to get it to recognize the checkbox is unchecked, and make sure a 0 gets sent to the db, or a 1 if checked? That's how I've been doing it

With the select, I'm not sure what do to, or how to target the value in between the select tags to show instead of the value="" value, while making sure the value="" value gets stored in the db.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: Attempted to make it work with the suggested edits but I'm afraid neither suggestion worked for me. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Selects are working great now. I still haven't solved the checkbox problem. I can get it to set it to zero and unchecked but not the other way around.

Comment: When I include  && is_disp.length > 0 , alert("enter something.") pops up so with this code, when checking the box from a unchecked state, it's not sending anything. I hate checkboxes. I could just use a combo box with "yes" and "no" but that feels like giving up.

Comment: Apparently, this is a much more complex problem. None of the solutions offered worked. I have given up trying to get a simple checkbox to work with ajax and jQuery. For all my "display" booleans, I'll just use a combo box with "yes" and "no" and have it show nice green 'check' or red 'x' instead of the checkbox. Implemented and working perfectly. It's one extra click but not the end of the world. Maybe I'll discover a solution someday. Thank for everyone's help! I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a select boxes option's text use the `:selected` selector along with `.text()`

```
var text = $("#selectID option:selected").text();
var value = $("#selectID option:selected").val();
```

for checkbox check the return of `.prop("checked")`

```
var check = $("#checkboxID").prop("checked") ? 1: 0;
```

EDIT:

```
var parent_nav_text = $("#parent_nav_input_"+ID+" option:selected").text();
```

Then in your ajax function

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin_nav_edit.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#name_"+ID).html(name);
                $("#position_"+ID).html(position);
                $("#parent_nav_"+ID).html(parent_nav_text);
                $("#is_disp_"+ID).html(is_disp);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried implementing your suggestion but the way I tried it  didn't work for me. I updated my code with my attempt. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the text of the options? cause it looks like you are trying to use it as a selector? are they valid selectors?

Comment: Pretty sure. I'm using the same method on the other fields and they are working properly. Now neither the checkbox nor selects are working. The combo box isn't even showing up.

Comment: @sinrise i am talking about this: `$(parent_nav_sel_txt).hide()`, if the value of 'parent_nav_sel_txt' is not a proper selector like `.someClassName` or `#someId` or `someTagName` etc it will not select the correct element.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm still getting the hang of jQuery. Thanks. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what to do with the vars 'text' and 'value' then, or 'check' for that matter. I tried it with .is(":checked") and prop("checked"). No luck.

Comment: _"With the select, I'm not sure what do to, or how to target the value in between the select tags"_ i was just showing how to get the value and how to get the text, do with them whatever it is you need to do with them. As for the check, what do you mean no luck? are you getting an error or something?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I need it to display the text for the selected option in the div (parent_nav_ID) after hiding the input. Currently it's showing the input value when it hides input field. When the page first loads, or when you refresh, it shows the text in the div again.

Comment: I'm getting a "syntax error, unrecognized expression" with var parent_nav_txt = $("$parent_nav_input_"+ID+" option:selected").text();

Comment: because you have the dollar sign at the beginning of the string,

Comment: ugh. Thanks for catching that. I'm still lost on what to do next. How to I get it to show the text from the option that's selected, instead of its value?

Comment: Woohoo! That works perfectly. You are awesome. Now, I just have to figure out how to get that pesky checkbox to stay checked :)

Answer (score 0):

A call to `.val()` on a checkbox will always return the value it is set with in the DOM. You should instead do this:

```
var is_disp = $("#is_disp_input_"+ID).is(':checked');
```

the `.is()` jQuery function returns true if the element has the CSS selector, in this case `:checked`.

Also, on the server, you should check if the checkbox variable is true or false using `if(!empty($_POST['myvar'])) {}` instead of `if(isset($_POST['myvar'])) {}` because `isset()` will return true even if myvar is zero or false!

Comment: Thanks! I think this is going to work but I realized the problem might also lie in my php. I'm using if(isset($_POST['is_disp'])) { $admin_nav->is_disp = 1; } else { $admin_nav->is_disp = 0; } to update the record, which worked before the ajax. I also tried just $admin_nav->is_disp = mysql_prep($_POST['is_disp']); One way will update 1 to 0 and the other 0 to 1 but not both ways, if that makes sense. How should I rewrite my update statement? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know what mysql_prep is... but your first if/else condition seems fine. Except I would use `if(!empty($_POST['is_disp']))` instead of `isset`. you can have a variable set to 0 (zero) and isset() would still return true which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks. mysql_prep() is my anti sql-injection function. I see what you mean about isset but that's what I've been using since the way the html form checkboxes seem to work is you set it's value to a static string (in my case 1, since it's a boolean) and if it's checked it sends the value in the POST but if not, it sends nothing. I'm afraid that's also the reason I'm having trouble getting it work with ajax. I searched a long time for an answer before posting so either I'm way overcomplicating it, or I'm missing something else fundamental. Even jqGrid doesn't seem to address checkboxes.

Comment: Well, if you were not using Ajax before, then the browser would NOT send the POST field for checkboxes that are not checked. However, now that you're using ajax and building a dataString, you're always sending is_disp to the server. Therefore `isset()` will return true every time.

Comment: I think I've almost got it. It successfully unchecks, and saves 0 to the db, but it won't work to set it back to 1, if checked... I'm now just using: if(!empty($_POST['is_disp'])) { $admin_nav->is_disp = 1; } else { $admin_nav->is_disp = 0; } But it's still not working.

Comment: Still playing around with but no luck. :(

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question, since this is getting pretty confusing. Anyway, to check a box to checked from the server, when outputting the HTML for the checkbox, set the "checked" attribute like this: `<input type="checkbox" checked value="1" />`. As long as the checked attribute is present the browser will default it to checked on page load.

Comment: I guess so. I understand how checkboxes work, and I'm pretty sure that's the reason it's not so simple to get them to work with jQuery. I thought it was really simple what I am trying to accomplish. I just want the checkbox to be inline editable along with the other fields. So far, no suggestions have worked.